# phpMyAdmin импортирует только часть базы

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

Пытаюсь залить базу данных на 190 мб, жду около 5 минут все вроде заливает, но только не все таблицы, кто может стыкался с таким, может какие-то конфиги покрутить?

Comment: Попробуйте выполнить импорт из командной строки `mysql -u username -p database_name < file.sql`

Comment: У вас в настройках php ограничение на объем файлов и время выполнения скрипта. Ваша проблема скорее всего во втором.

Comment: Подозреваю что автор не очень в курсе по поводу командной строки и речь идет о каком то дешевом хостинге. 
И первый  и второй комментарий совершенно справедливы, однако я подозреваю что не первый ответ ни второй вы применить не можете. Остается пару вариантов - вам нужно подключится к базе данных через что либо вменяемое чем PHPMyadmin либо разделить свой дамп на таблицы и заливать их поочередно. О последнем можете прочитать тут https://stackoverflow.com/questions/132902/how-do-i-split-the-output-from-mysqldump-into-smaller-files/

Comment: zalex, как раз таки благодарен авторам первых двух ответов, а у вас много для меня лично лишнего в тексте как мне кажется